# I want to use an exe file programatically

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exe

I am using a software named Daisy 2.02 Validator and it is with GUI but i want to access it programatically so that i can control all the validation process through my C# project. I am unable to find any help about it's libraries, any .net Api or any DOS command for controlling it. Please provide me help.

Thanks,
Regard,
Muhammad Waqas

Answer (score 6):

If it's a .NET executable, try and use ILDASM.exe or better still - use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to find out whether it has a public API. You may then be able to add it as a reference (all you need to do is simply rename the .exe to .dll) to your project or alternatively load it as an assembly and use reflection to use its API.

Obviously the first option is much preferred.

If it isn't a .NET executable, you could use scraping, but you would have to profile your app for that first and work out what low level windows messages and controls it responds to. Bit of a nightmare.

Comment: scraping, Can u please scraping what is it?

Comment: It's a way of using low level Win32 API's and messages to retrieve window/control information. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375117/screen-scraping-a-windows-application-in-c

Answer (score 3):

from what I [see](http://code.google.com/p/daisytools/) Daisy 2.02 Validator is an **open source project**.
if the API is not implemented you can just add it  yourself

Answer (score 0):

Worst case maybe send keystrokes to it.