# Extracting data from a table in a windows application

Tags: c#, windows, data-extraction

I'm attempting to extract data from a windows application. The data is displayed like an excel table within the program, but it has no functionality for automatically exporting or parsing the data for real-time automated analysis, which is what I need.

I have seen the thread at [Screen-scraping a windows application in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375117/screen-scraping-a-windows-application-in-c-sharp) and going through it got me to a point where I can extract data from notepad perfectly, but doesn't seem to work for the table format that this program is displaying.  My guess is that WM_GETTEXT isn't really designed to get the data this program displays. It could wind up being 10 colums x 1000 rows feasibly, but maybe that doesn't matter.  Anyways, I don't know what might be the correct way to go about getting this data.  Or maybe WM_GETTEXT can do it and I just don't have it set up correctly? I'm not sure, but I've tried it a lot of different ways and none have gotten me anything but the title of the window (yes I did also find the child handles and those returned nothing)

Hypothetically I might be able to get it to work by sending the program keystrokes and copying/pasting the data into a file, saving, and then reading that file, but my thought is that might be cumbersome and weird as I'll need my program to check the data for updates pretty regularly.

I know it can be done, I just don't know where to go to figure it out.  I haven't ever had a need to interact with an external program before so this is all new to me. Most of the material I find online has to do with screen scraping web pages, which this is not. I'm using C#, but I'd use whatever language I need to in order to make it work. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It's quite likely that you are only seeing a picture, or only the controls that are on screen actually exist. If you can use Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, then I'd do that.

Comment: Well it's not a rendered image like a PNG, if that's what you mean.  I can manually copy+paste the data straight from the program into excel with zero problems, other than the fact that I don't want to do that manually 30 times a minute.  But I'll tally your comment as a vote for "just try to do it by sending keystrokes and saving it externally." I didn't want to do it that way, but if that's really the best way, I can look into it. Thanks!

Comment: I mean that an application which is handling a large amount of data is likely to be drawing a picture directly to the screen, rather than arranging a set of ui controls that respond to WM_GETTEXT.